# Telegram webhook doesn't send any post message

Tags: vb.net, bots, telegram

I'm working on a telegram bot and I'm setting the webhook which calls a web page that should take the posted message and file it in a txt file.
I wrote a simple code but I can't see the posted message but writes the string ss only which means that the page is called.
Any suggestion?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    If Not IsPostBack = True Then
        Dim ss As String = "ss=prova"
        Dim ss1 As String
        ss1 = Request.Form.ToString


        ' ii = Request.Form(0)
        aurum.scriviappunto(ss + ss1) 'writes string on txt file
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As an aside, the "= True" is unnecessary.

Comment: Did you inspect the value of `Request.Form.ToString`?

Comment: yes aurum.scriviappunto is a function who puts string i a txt file but I can see only ss=prova in txt which means the page is called but nothing has been posted